# DRF - M2M through serializer for ImageField gives UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, many-to-many, serialization

I want to serialize a model using M2M through relation. Its working fine for all other fields except `ImageField`. Below are my model and serializer files:

`models.py`

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField('Description', max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField('Price', default=0)
    image = models.ImageField('Product Image', null=True, blank=True)


class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField('User ID', default="1000", max_length=255)
    items = models.ManyToManyField("Product", through='CartActions', blank=True)
    modified = models.DateField('Last Modified')


class CartActions(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart = models.ForeignKey('Cart', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
```

`serializers.py`

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'price', 'image']


class CartSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    items = CartActionsSerializer(source='cartactions_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'items']


class CartActionsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='product.name')
    price = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='product.price')
    image = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='product.image')  # Adding this line gives error

    class Meta:
        model = CartActions
        fields = ['name', 'price', 'image', 'quantity']
```

This is the error I'm getting when hitting the API:

> UnicodeDecodeError at **/store/api/cart/**
>
> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

This is the sample response I'm getting from `/api/products` API:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Product 1",
    "description": "This is a sample description",
    "price": 500,
    "image": "http://192.168.43.210:9000/media/sample_product.jpeg"
}
```

I've tried almost all references in stackoverflow and other websites but I cannot find the exact same issue anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this serializer you did not define field serializers explicitly, only mentioned field list:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'price', 'image']
```

DRF [recognized](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/d985c7cbb999b2bc18a109249c583e91f4c27aec/rest_framework/serializers.py#L869) `image` as an ImageField and applied [serializers.ImageField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#imagefield) serializer which has `use_url` argument:

> [use_url](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py#L1578) - If set to True then URL string values will be used for the output representation. If set to False then filename string values will be used for the output representation. Defaults to the value of the UPLOADED_FILES_USE_URL settings key, which is True unless set otherwise.

Thus it was serialized with `ProductSerializer` as an URL rather then binary picture or a filename.

In the other serializer you have defined field serializer explicitly:

```
class CartActionsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    ...
    image = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='product.image')
```

[ReadOnlyField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#readonlyfield) is a generic serializer which outputs `source` [as it is](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/d985c7cbb999b2bc18a109249c583e91f4c27aec/rest_framework/fields.py#L1844). Thus 'product.image' returns an ImageField instance which is not an URL or path - it's the whole object with many attributes.

So try using a specific field serializer

```
serializers.ImageField(read_only=True, ...)
```

or make source more specific with [default](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) to avoid errors if image is missing

```
serializers.ReadonlyField(source='product.image.url', default=None, ...)
```

or access this value via [method](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

```
class CartActionsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    ...
    image = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_image(self, obj):
        return obj.product.image.url
```